# How to avoid global variables in WordPress

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, variables, global

I've had a few instances now in which I create, say, a variable with css called

.slider

and it affected alot of stuff on my page.
How do I avoid this?

Also, I've written alot of JavaScript in a plugin, and ended up doing changes to global variables.

Is there a way to avoid this? All of the sudden all the images might change on a page, or something in the javascript code changes stuff on the page.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your code looks like this:

```
var my_global_var = 123;

function do_something_with_vars() {
   //   ... your logic here

}

function do_something_else_with_vars() {
   //   ... your logic here
}
```

One way to avoid global variables conflict is to use anonymous functions:

The above code can be re-written as:

```
(function(){
   var my_global_var = 123;
   function do_something_with_vars() { ... };
   function do_something_else() {  ... };
})();
// here, my_global_var is out of scope.
```